# PayPal Sandbox does not send IPN's

Tags: paypal

I am having trouble testing IPN with Sandbox.  I have been testing my setup with the IPN Simulator and that works very well. However when I make a test transaction using the Sandbox I get no output.  I have looked in the IPN history and there is nothing shown there.  I have also checked my url's.
I am new to this aspect of PayPal so there may well be something I'm missing.  Any help would be much appreciated.